# How to download a picture in a python package

Tags: setuptools, python-packaging, python-importlib

I am working on a game engine built on pyGame and am trying to package it. I would like some default images  to be saved and downloaded with the package when its downloaded. (thru pip and pypi)

I loaded the package onto the testPyPi and then pip installed the package. I got the error:

```
'pyEngine2D/data/null.png' found in working directory 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\test'.
```

pyEngine2D is the name of the package
I think it may be a problem with relative file links. Is there a way to see if the image got downloaded with the rest of the package and how should I change the importing of the image.
The code to import the image is:

```
screen = ScreenInit(360,480, 60, 100, "pyEngine2D/data/null.png", "MyGame")
```

```
if self.icon:
    pygame_icon = pygame.image.load(self.icon)
    pygame.display.set_icon(pygame_icon)
```

Here is the full package:
https://github.com/ddd-Makbema/pyEngine2D

Comment: This has been asked countless times already. -- Use this doc to know how to package non-Python data files with *setuptools*: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html -- Use [`importlib.resources.files()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.resources.html#importlib.resources.files) to access these data files from your Python code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+package+data

Comment: Adding an include statement to the manifest,in file for the image as well as the include_package_data=True worked to allow the image to be added properly. Thank you for the help.